# Ubuntu 64-Bit Kernal Wont Run In VM (check error below)

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualbox, 64-bit

So when I installed Ubuntu 64-bit (I've tried changing it to 32-bit and nothing changed.) I ran it inside a VM (Oracle VM VirtualBox) So, I turn on Ubuntu, insert the ISO and.... I get this message (typed by hand, because I could not copy it, please excuse any mistakes): Please help

```
[55.004077] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/Virtual, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[55.005668] Call Trace:
[55.006068] dump_stack+0x63/0x8b
[55.006068] panic+0xe4/0x224
[55.007020] do_exit+0xb3e/0xb40
[55.007506] ?__schedule+0x43/0xb0
[55.008057] do_group_exit+0x43/0xb0
[55.008820] SyS_exit_group+0x43/0xb0
[55.009597] do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
[55.010359] entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
[55.011330] RIP: 0033:0x7fe0c5483056
[55.012092] RSP:002b:00007ffe0c5483056 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX 00000000000000e7
[55.013650] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fe0c5489ce0 RCX: 00007fe0c5483056
[55.014941] RDX: 000000000000007f RSI: 000000000000003c RDI: 000000000000007f
[55.016233] RBP: 00007ffe49fabda0 R08: 00000000000000e7 R09: 00007ffe49faad64
[55.018696] R10: 0000000000000020 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 0000000000000011
[55.020032] R13: 00007fe0c5674010 R14: 00007fe0c5673f80 R15: 00007fe0c568f170
[55.021220] Kernel Offset: 0xae00000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation rang0xffffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)
[55.022555] ---[end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exit code=0x00007f00
[55.022555]
```

Comment: This happened when I just boot up the thing. Im not truly sure.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean either by attempt to install or before i installed it. So ill just specify what I did. 1. I downloaded the ISO off this website. 2. I booted up Oracle VirtualBox, and I had it detect the ISO. Lastly, I booted up the OS and it showed Ubuntu 16.04. After that it showed this error message.

Comment: Seems like you were attempting to boot the installed VM guest (not the install .iso). Delete the VM Guest, re-download the install .iso, and clean-install again. There are many possible causes of a first-boot panic, but most are due to a corrupted-during-download installer or a corrupted-during-install system.